# convert and format string to an array of characters in swift

Tags: swift

how do I convert this string to an array of characters ignoring the first 2 characters and line breaks (\n) or spaces ?
so I do have this:

```
var leds = """
1 1
XXX
000
00X
"""
```

to return this to me as a result:

```
['x','x','x','0','0','0','0','0','x']
```

I have this, but it doesn't ignore the spaces, line breaks or the number of the first line:

```
let characters = Array(leds)
print(characters)
```

thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Split the string into an array of lines, and drop the first line. Then use `flatMap` to map each line to an array of characters and concatenate the result.

```
let array = leds.components(separatedBy: .newlines)
    .dropFirst()
    .flatMap(Array.init)

print(array) // ["X", "X", "X", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "X"]
```

With `map` instead of `flatMap` you would get a “nested array” corresponding to the rows and columns from the input string:

```
let board = leds.components(separatedBy: .newlines)
    .dropFirst()
    .map(Array.init)

print(board) // [["X", "X", "X"], ["0", "0", "0"], ["0", "0", "X"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

This could also be useful-

```
if let firstLine = leds.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.newlines).first {
        let removeFirstLineStr = leds.replacingOccurrences(of: firstLine, with: "")
        let characters = String(removeFirstLineStr.filter { !" \n\t\r".contains($0) })
        print(Array(characters))
    }
```

**OR**

```
func getCharacters() {
    guard let firstLineStr = leds.components(separatedBy: "\n").first else {
        return
    }
    let removeFirstLineStr = leds.replacingOccurrences(of: firstLineStr, with: "")
    let characters = String(removeFirstLineStr.filter { !" \n\t\r".contains($0) })
    print(Array(characters))
}
```

Comment: MUCHAS GRACIAS FUNCIONA